# How do I integrate SnapEngage with Adwords?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-ads-api

I would like to track a chat on SnapEngage on our website as a conversion on Google Adwords.

Has anyone done this before?

Thanks

Comment: What is the specific event that you'd like to track?  Is it simply that the chat window launched?  Or that some dialog was exchanged between both parties?  I'm not familiar with SnapEngage, but I'm guessing you can do something with AdWords Conversion Import to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Event API - http://developer.snapengage.com/javascript-api/javascript-events/

Just choose the event/events that you want to track and place your GA (or any other tracking code) within the event callback function

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's important to provide sample code to justify your answer. What if the link just dies away some day?